# BotFrameworkV4- Images are not getting displayed in the Adaptive Card in Microsoft Teams

Tags: json, image, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm just beginning to work with BotFramework. I'm trying to display an Adaptive Card in Microsoft Teams and I'm working with the code I downloaded from https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search

I see that the image URL being returned in the response JSON is correct and I can paste it in the browser and the image displays just fine, but in the card, the image is displayed as "undefined". I see that Teams changes the URL to - `https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/content?url=[original_url]`

I've tried changing the Azure Blob Firewall settings to "Allow All Networks" and I have added my application domain and urlp.asm.skype.com to the `validDomains[]` configuration in the manifest.json, but I still have the issue with my images.

[image]

The JSON I'm using is as follows -
the ${thumbnailurl} contains the url to the thumbnail image.

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.2",
  "backgroundImage": "https://www.beautycolorcode.com/abcdef.png",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "ColumnSet",
          "columns": [
            {
              "type": "Column",
              "width": "auto",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "Image",
                  "size": "large",
                  "style": "default",
                  "width": "100px",
                  "spacing": "extraLarge",
                  "url": "http://<myHostname>/xdownload/thumbnail/%257B%2522app%2522%253A%2522NH-vanilla-search%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522%255C%252FFS%255C%252FDemo%2BFiles%255C%252F%257CEnron%2BData%255C%252Fenron1992.pdf%2522%257D/file.jpg"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "Column",
              "width": "stretch",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "Enron Documents 1992 ENRON CORP",
                  "wrap": true,
                  "color": "accent",
                  "size": "medium",
                  "weight": "bolder",
                  "spacing": "padding",
                  "fontType": "default",
                  "horizontalAlignment": "left"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "DC 20585 | 5 -- ': ... L. Lay Chairman and CEO **Enron** Corporation\r\nP.O. Box 1188 Houston, ... 1992, and for your comments... fired\r\nelectricity generation over the ... gas prices currently offered by\r\n**Enron** and others. Natural gas power ... coal or nuclear plants. In\r\naddition... America's strengths to achieve aggressive ... L. Lay,\r\nchairman and CEO of **Enron** Corp., in testimony today before the ...\r\nproductivity, prosperity and global leadership\r\n",
          "wrap": true,
          "maxLines": 6,
          "spacing": "padding",
          "fontType": "default",
          "weight": "default",
          "size": "small"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "FactSet",
      "facts": [
        {
          "title": "Source:",
          "value": "\r\n  /File System/Sample Data/Enron Data/\r\n"
        },
        {
          "title": "Format:",
          "value": "pdf"
        },
        {
          "title": "Relevancy:",
          "value": "85.04401%"
        }
      ],
      "separator": true,
      "spacing": "extraLarge"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
      "title": "Document Preview",
      "url": "http://<myHostname>/app/NH-vanilla-search/#/preview?id=%2FFS%2FDemo+Files%2F%7CEnron+Data%2Fenron1992.pdf&query=%7B%22name%22%3A%22Custom_Query%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22enron+data%22%7D",
      "style": "positive",
      "width": "stretch"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd greatly appreciate your inputs here.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question? Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It looks like you're showing us an Adaptive Card template. Can you show us the actual card after the data has been applied? You can use dummy data if you don't want us to see the real stuff, but it needs to be an actual image URL that you can reproduce the problem with.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney - I updated the json in my question. i've tested that if I use a URL available for public access like the one below , the image displays just fine.   https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE2883D?ver=3026&q=90&m=6&h=50&w=50&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&f=jpg&o=t&aim=true

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you very much for the information!

Comment: Why haven't you accepted it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after giving it some thought.

Instead of image url, I did sent data URI for that Image.

1. Goto https://ezgif.com/image-to-datauri
2. Upload your image and click on convert
3. You will get something like `<img src="data:XXXXXX..etc" />`
4. Copy the content side src tag --> this part --> (data:XXXX...)
5. Now in the Adaptive card payload/JSON send this instead of image url

[Check the postman URL screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzLYZ.png)

[Images appear in Teams Adaptive card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3DWA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Teams cannot access that image. Any image you expect pretty much any channel client to display will need to be publicly accessible. Use a public image URL.

Comment: Thank you Kyle! The problem is the web application renders the thumbnail images on demand and they are not publicly accessible . I guess there is no workaround for this.

Comment: Of course there's a workaround. Just have your web application upload the images somewhere with a public address. You could use your own site like the one your bot is hosted on, or you could use something like Imgur: https://apidocs.imgur.com/